# Auto-refresh OAuth2 token for scheduled runs not possible, really?

Tags: postman

I use Postman and OAuth2 to run a request to the Google Drive API.
I want to schedule that request to run every morning.

Now I've read that:

> You can use auto-refresh when manually sending the request. Auto-refresh isn't used for scheduled runs or monitors for the same collection.
> https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#refreshing-an-oauth-20-token

Is there really no way to auto-refresh the OAuth2 token so it is possible to repreatedly let it run?

Thank you and best regards,
Florian